# In that instant vs At that instant

Tags: meaning, word-choice

> In that instant, xxx

or

> At that instant, xxx

I know that "at that instant" is the more correct way of saying it, but can "in that instant" work as well?

> At the instant that he jumped...

vs

> In the instant that he jumped...

Would both be correct in that case, if "that" and "the" were switched?

Comment: What do [Google Ngrams for "in that instant" and "at that instant"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+that+instant%2Cat+that+instant&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20that%20instant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20that%20instant%3B%2Cc0) suggest?

Comment: "In that instant" must be a frozen form; semantically, an _instant_ is a very small stretch of time, hardly a large volume, which is what _in_ requires. _At_ would be the norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is not spacious, but I think one could draw some useful distinctions.

I would use *at* when I wanted to denote a point in time at which something happened,

> At that instant I fumbled my phone into the pond.

and *in* to denote a very small space of time during which something happened:

> In that instant I saw my phone falling from my fingers and cartwheeling into the pond.

Again, it's a slight difference, and you *could* use either preposition in either sentence, but as a writer looking to wring the most meaning out of words, I would recommend the above.